# How to append data in conditional way inside of each function of Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Hi Developer feel new for this, I quite over think how to append conditional in jquery.

I already solved this problem, but I used the if statement in the laravel, The question is how to do it in jquery.

I will show you the output looks like., as you can see alternate direction happen. if the direction value is equal to "RIGHT" then the content will be go to the right else, the direction will go to the left.
[image: Output]

My codes in laravel is this.

```
@foreach($historytable as $history_content)
    <li>
        @if($history_content->content_section == 'Right')
            <div class="direction-r">
                <div class="flag-wrapper">
                    <span class="hexa"></span>

                    <span class="time-wrapper"><span class="time">{{$history_content->content_title}}</span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    {!! $history_content->content !!}
                </div>
            </div>


        @else
            <div class="direction-l">
                <div class="flag-wrapper">
                    <span class="hexa"></span>

                    <span class="time-wrapper"><span class="time">{{$history_content->content_title}}</span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="desc">
                    {!! $history_content->content !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif  
    </li>
@endforeach
```

So now moving forward, I revamp my codes and I want to transfer it to jquery, 
I have here my function in my jquery let me show you,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:8000/api/story',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success:function(response) {
            console.log(response);

            var historytable = response[0].historytable;
            $.each(historytable, function (index, el) {

            var stringify_historytable = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(el));
            var condition_direction = stringify_historytable['content_section'];
            var condition_content_title = stringify_historytable['content_title'];

            console.log(condition_direction);

            var data;

            data += "<li>" +((condition_direction == 'Right' ) ? 'Right' : '')+ "</li>";

            $('#time_line_data').html(data);

          });
        },
        error:function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

My Html Look likes this, I just want to append the result to this id.

```
<ul class="timeline" id="time_line_data">

</ul>
```

Comment: This should be ver simple by just adding the corresponding CSS classes. Somehting like if( condition === "right") {addClass('yourClass')} else etc

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand you right but i think you want to add `<li>` elements to the `<ul>`
Instead of `.html()`  you want to use [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/)
like this `$('#time_line_data').append(data);`

I created a small example for you
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvBogw